# brew upgrade redis says it has installed latest version but cannot use it

Tags: macos, redis, homebrew

I was using redis **3.2.0**, recently I ran the command

```
brew upgrade redis
```

which gave me an error:

> Error: redis 4.0.1 already installed

but when I run redis using `redis-server` it is still using 3.2.0. How can I use the latest version?

Answer (score 0):

it seems when I run

```
brew services start redis
```

it uses the latest version of redis

Answer (score 0):

`brew upgrade` doesn’t restart services for you; your old `redis-server` is still running even if you install a more up-to-date version.

Use `brew services restart redis` or a similar command to stop the current server and start a new instance.